# Mysql (MariaDB) connect with https://www.phpmyadmin.co

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I would like to manage my database with https://www.phpmyadmin.co. But it doesn't want to bind. After like 20 Seconds there comes an errror.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tene.png)

I can use it for my minecraft plugins with localhost. Here are my setup commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;
CREATE USER 'myuser'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'userpsw432';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON data.* TO 'myuser'@localhost;
```

I think it has something to do with @localhost but I'm not that familiar with linux yet.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That phpmyadmin.co thing is a web service, running on some server on the net someplace, that connects to its users' databases and serves as a phpmyadmin database client.

To use it your database must be on the network and not firewalled, and you must give it your machine's public internet address.

`localhost` isn't a public address, though. I suspect your localhost database server is not accessible that way.

You probably need some substitute for phpmyadmin that you can run locally. HeidiSql? MySql Workbench? SquirrelSQL?